# How to make a responsive form in HTML5 and embed it in slider?

Tags: html, forms

how to DESIGN a form using html5 and CSS3, and them embed it in slider , and also make other forms which can open as popups when a button is clicked .

and how to specify to whom the data will be emailed to and what would be the format of that email ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Twitter Bootstrap

http://getbootstrap.com/

it is way of making responsive sites

Tutorials

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/index.htm?utm_source=tuicool